# /null being appended to Wordpress files, maybe via Shopp plugin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

got a fairly wierd one that I can't replicate. I'm using the 'redirection' plugin in my wordpress setup, it is showing that almost 50% of the hits on the site are requesting urls with /null on the end - that results in a 404 error.

I'm using the Shopp plugin as well, and permalinks all round.

Has anyone experienced this?

Also, is there a way I can use .htaccess to say if there is /null on the end - then remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No idea as to the source of this addition, but you can use .htaccess to get rid of it. Place this in your .htaccess after loading and enabling mod_rewrite and setting AllowOverride All:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?null$ $1 [L,R=301,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: that works 90% so thanks, for some reason when it is atached the the home url it doesn't work e.g. example.com/null is not redirecting to example.com